# How can retrieve unique field of a table from DB2 IBM

Tags: sql, db2

I need a script to retrieve all unique and primary keys from a given table in DB2/IBM

I tried to use something like :

```
select * from SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'Table1'
```

but it does not contain information about Primary keys nor UNIQUE Keys.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at this table I think:

```
select i.index_name , i.column_names , i.unique
from syspindex as i
where table_schema = 'lib'
and table_name = 'file'
```